# Immortal cursed hero

Tags: story-identification, manga

I'm looking for a manga where the main character and his party defeat the demon king, but he curses the hero so he is immortal and slowly turning into a monster. He has the ability to absorb everything and he also absorbs a  magic/holy sword in the later chapters. He lives in a forest with one maid. The fake hero comes to kill him but fails. That's when the real hero gets the magic/holy sword. It's not a isekai.

Comment: Definitely one maid, and not four? [Shindou Yuusha to Maid Onee-san](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/shindou-yuusha-to-maid-onee-san)

Comment: Thanks this is the one i was looking for :)

Answer (score 5):

As confirmed in the comments, this is *[Shindou Yuusha to Maid Onee-san](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/shindou-yuusha-to-maid-onee-san)*.

> After defeating the Demon King and saving the world, **Shion was exiled to the border**. Here, the strongest Hero enjoyed his slow life with **4 capable onee-san maids**.

Synopsis covers much of the question, except there are four maids instead of just one.